# Pyspark RDD ReducebyKey()

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

Hi I am trying to understand where is the problem in my code:

```py
rdd_avg=sc.parallelize([("a",10),("b",15),("c",20),("a",8)])
rdd_sp1=rdd_avg.map(lambda x: (x,1))
rdd_sp1.collect()
rdd_sp2=rdd_sp1.reduceByKey(lambda a,b:(a[0]+b[0],a[1]+b[1]))
rdd_sp2.collect()
```

The output I am getting is

`[(('c', 20), 1), (('a', 10), 1), (('b', 15), 1), (('a', 8), 1)]`

But I am trying to get.

`[(('c', 20), 1), (('a', 18), 2), (('b', 15), 1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the first element of the tuple must be the `key`, and the second, the `value`. In your example, when you do the first `map` (`rdd_avg.map(lambda x: (x,1))`), you are using as key the hole tuple. So these are your keys: `('c', 20)`, `('a', 10)`, `('b', 15)`, and `('a', 8)`. Note that the key `('a', 10)` is different from the key `('a', 8)`. Your keys should be `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.

This is the code fixed:

```py
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([("a",10), ("b",15), ("c",20),("a",8)])
>>> # the first element of the tuple is x[0], not x
>>> rdd_sp1 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], 1)))
>>> rdd_sp1.collect()
[('a', (10, 1)), ('b', (15, 1)), ('c', (20, 1)), ('a', (8, 1))]
```

> Note how now the first element of the tuple is the key, not a tuple

```py
>>> rdd_sp2 = rdd_sp1.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]))
>>> rdd_sp2.collect()
[('b', (15, 1)), ('c', (20, 1)), ('a', (18, 2))]
```

> With the keys issue fixed, we can effectively reduce by key

```py
>>> rdd_avg = rdd_sp2.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0] / x[1][1]))
>>> rdd_avg.collect()
[('b', 15.0), ('c', 20.0), ('a', 9.0)]
```

Comment: Thanks its clear now what I was missing.